# SwiftUI ForEach array indices not rendering

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a simple view:

```swift
struct SomeView: View {
  @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel()
  var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { fullView in
      ScrollView {
        VStack(spacing: 40) {
          ForEach(self.viewModel.list) { item in
            Text(item.name)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is working. But I need work with index. And I tried to change my `ForEach` loop:

```
ForEach(self.viewModel.list.indices) { index in
  Text(self.viewModel.list[index].name)
}
```

But this time `ForEach` does not render anything. But on console written:

```
ForEach<Range<Int>, Int, ModifiedContent<ModifiedContent<GeometryReader<ModifiedContent<ModifiedContent<ModifiedContent<...>, _FrameLayout>, _TransactionModifier>> count (10) != its initial count (0). `ForEach(_:content:)` should only be used for *constant* data. Instead conform data to `Identifiable` or use `ForEach(_:id:content:)` and provide an explicit `id`!
```

My model is `Identifiable`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have both, like in below

```
struct SomeView: View {
  @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel()
  var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { fullView in
      ScrollView {
        VStack(spacing: 40) {
          ForEach(Array(self.viewModel.list.enumerated()), id: \.1) { index, item in
            Text(item.name)
            // ... use index here as needed
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```